# When trying to get all webparts on a Sharepoint Online page using C# CSOM, I get 0 returned (while there *are* webparts on my page)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

So I'm using C# CSOM code to try and get all webparts, so that I can remove one. My Sharepoint Online page is just a standard modern teamsite page with nothing changed yet. I want to get all webparts, then remove the quick links standard webpart using csom. Here's my code:

```
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oFile = 
                Context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/CR-WST-GYM-20130306/SitePages/Home.aspx");
            LimitedWebPartManager wpManager = oFile.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
            /*Context.Load(wpManager.WebParts,
                wps => wps.Include(
                wp => wp.WebPart.Title));*/
            Context.Load(wpManager);
            Context.ExecuteQueryRetry();

            WebPartDefinitionCollection wpDefinitionCollection = wpManager.WebParts;
            Context.Load(wpDefinitionCollection);
            Context.ExecuteQueryRetry();
```

It loads, but wpManager.WebParts contains 0 values & has a count of 0... how is this possible, when there's already standard webparts added to a newly created teamsite? Shouldn't I get at least a couple? What might I be doing wrong?

This code is taken from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539301(v%3Doffice.14) .

EDIT: I've also added a new webpart via UI to my main page to see if I get "1" as value, but it's still 0 ...

Answer (score 0):

For "**modern**" site pages [`OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/officedevpnp.core.pages?view=sharepointpnpcoreonline-2.18.1709.0) has been introduced to manage web parts instead of [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539892%28v%3Doffice.14%29)

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve the list of client-side web parts on page

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
      ctx.Credentials = GetCredentials(userName, password);

      var page = OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages.ClientSidePage.Load(ctx, "Home.aspx");
      var webParts = page.Controls.Where(c => c.Type.Name == "ClientSideWebPart").ToList();
}
```

**Prerequisites**

[`SharePointPnPCoreOnline` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/)

**Reference**

[Customizing "modern" site pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages)

Comment: I get 0 web parts of that. Seems like ther eis a bug and has been for a while.

Answer (score 0):

PnP isn't needed. This is working for me.

```
CamlQuery allPagesQuery = new CamlQuery();
ListItemCollection pageItems = list.GetItems(allPagesQuery);
ctx.Load(pageItems, pi => pi.Include(i => i.Id, i => i.DisplayName));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var item in pageItems)
{
   ctx.Load(item, i => i.File, i => i.File.ServerRelativeUrl);
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
   LimitedWebPartManager wpManager = 
      item.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
   ctx.Load(wpManager, wpm => wpm.WebParts.Include(wp => wp.WebPart.Title, wp => wp.Id));
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
   foreach (WebPartDefinition wp in wpManager.WebParts)
   {
       log4.DebugFormat("Webpart in {0}: {1} [{2}]",
       item.File.ServerRelativeUrl, wp.WebPart.Title, wp.Id);
   }
}
```